# use ngFor loop in Angular 6 to dynamically create array of input elements and add dynamical validation based on template reference variables

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if, angular-template

I would like to create dynamically 3 input tags in Angular 6 to not copy/paste html code because that input elements have similar html and functionality.

For this purpose I created an array "reusableItems" inside component and initialize it :

```
    let numberOfInputElements = 3;        
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfInputElements; i++) {          
      this.reusableItems.push({
        answer: 'Answer ' + (i +1),
        passwordRecoveryAnswer: this.user['passwordRecoveryAnswer' + (i + 1)]
      });
    }
```

Then I put code inside my html :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dropDownDataManagerService.reusableItems" >
  <li class="col-xs-12 pl-lg pr0 pv-sm bd1-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-4 ph0 pt"> {{item.answerTitle}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" name={{item.answer}} ref-{{item.answer}}="ngModel" class="col-sm-12 k-textbox ph0"
             [(ngModel)]=item.passwordRecoveryAnswer
             [pattern]="[a-z]"
             required autocomplete="off"/>

    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

It seems works fine but then I need to add error messages when these fields will be empty and not match to pattern. Something like :

```
<div *ngIf="__{{item.answer}}__.errors?.required ">
  {{'Please provide an answer' | translate}}
</div>
<div *ngIf="__{{item.answer}}__.errors?.pattern">
  {{'Pattern is not match'}}
</div>
```

I don't know what should i put inside ngIf condition.
How can I do it if my template reference variables are comes from array?
Is anyone have ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular creates unique template reference variable for each embedded template so that  you can use the same template reference variable name inside ngFor loop:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of reusableItems">
    <li class="col-xs-12 pl-lg pr0 pv-sm bd1-bottom">
        <div class="col-xs-4 ph0 pt"> {{item.answerTitle}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name={{item.answer}} ref-answer="ngModel" class="col-sm-12 k-textbox ph0" [(ngModel)]="item.passwordRecoveryAnswer"
             [pattern]="'[a-z]'" required autocomplete="off" />
            <div *ngIf="answer.errors?.required">
                {{'Please provide an answer'}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="answer.errors?.pattern">
                {{'Pattern is not match'}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

In the code above I use the same name for each input in array

```html
ref-answer="ngModel" // or you can also use #answer="ngModel
```